# OTG mouse not working in Android 4?

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, usb, nexus-4, usb-on-the-go, mouse

I have Nexus 4 with broken touch screen and with Android 4.4.4 installed. I tried to connect a USB mouse using a OTG micro-usb adapter, but it doesn't work. The mouse doesn't even light up. Any idea why?

The adapter and the mouse are ok because I tried it on a different phone (Sony Xperia Z) and it works, mouse lights up, moves etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Nexus 4 doesn't support OTG** as you can read [here](https://m.androidcentral.com/android-advanced-usb-otg-nexus-4) and see related questions [on this site](https://android.stackexchange.com/search?q=Nexus+4+OTG)

It is possible if you overcome Kernel and power limitations as explained in [Android Advanced: USB OTG on the Nexus 4](https://m.androidcentral.com/android-advanced-usb-otg-nexus-4)

> The first problem with getting OTG working on the Nexus 4 is that the kernel does not support it. This has been solved using a modified version of Franco's kernel. The second problem is that the Nexus 4 cannot physically supply the necessary 5 volts. The way around this is to use a Y-cable, and supply the needed voltage from an outside power source such as a wall outlet or external battery pack. Some users have also reported success using a powered USB hub.

Comment: well that sucks :(